# How to concatenate a tab in a DB2 view field?

Tags: sql, view, db2, barcode

I've been attempting to create a Db2 (the database is hosted on an IBM i, running 7.3) view in which one of the fields (a character/char field) is constructed by concatenating several different pieces of data together. The catch is that between each of these fields of data, there needs to be a tab present which is used for delimiting the fields in a DataMatrix barcode.

The following [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlf161.aix.doc/language_ref/asciit.html) is an ASCII and EBCDIC character set that I'm using as a reference. I'm using the hexadecimal code for a horizontal tab as follows to try and concatenate the tabs in the character field that I'm constructing(e.g.):

```
select 'data1' || X'09' || 'data2' from 
sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Unfortunately, the only thing present, which results from the hexadecimal code (X'09') appears to be one single space, as follows:

```
Result set:    
data1 data2
```

When I use the resulting field in the view to generate a 2D barcode, there are actually no spaces at all delimiting the fields (seen after scanning said barcode). What's the trick to actually getting a tab to be rendered in a Db2 view field? Is there a different code or function I should be using? I've also tried using char(05) and char(09), but to no avail. In addition, I've tried casting the hexadecimal code as a character, as follows, but with no success:

```
select 'data1' || cast(X'09' as CHAR) || 'data2' from 
sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using x'05'?   I remember seeing tabs with this value on the mainframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try x'05' instead.

If you copy-past the following char sequence ("a" + "\tab" + "b") from some text editor, you get the result as described:

```
values hex('a   b');

|00001 |
|------|
|810582|
```

Comment: This worked for me - thanks again and much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use `CHR()` on both Db2 for LUW  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000778.html

> Returns the character that has the ASCII code value specified by the argument.

and Db2 for i https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscachr.htm

> The CHR function returns the EBCDIC character that has the ASCII code value specified by the argument.

```
values 'A' || CHR(9) || 'B'
```

returns

```
1  
---
A   B
```